# Compacting data in a pandas DataFrame by removing NaNs and shifting values left to reduce number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a data frame that looks as below:

```
5.29559     NaN     2.38176     NaN     0.51521     NaN     0.04454     0.00000     None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     0   NaN     NaN     0   NaN     NaN     0   2   None    None    None
4.32454     NaN     1.77600     NaN     0.04454     NaN     0.00000     None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     0   NaN     NaN     0   NaN     NaN     2   None    None    None    None
```

I am trying to generate a data frame by remove all the NaN values and trying to make the current data frame look like this:

```
5.29559     2.38176     0.51521     0.04454     0.00000     
      0           0           0           0           2         
4.32454     1.77600     0.04454     0.00000     
      0           0           0           2
```

Can someone please help?
I tried the dropna() method but it did not help.

Comment: The dropna method has arguments which you can find in its docs either on the web or via `help(df.dropna)`. You can use those.

Comment: I did the best I could to make the title of your question more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try stacking to eliminate nans, then reset the index for each level and finally unstack again:

```
(df.stack()
   .groupby(level=0)
   .apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True))
   .unstack())

         0        1        2        3    4
0  5.29559  2.38176  0.51521  0.04454  0.0
1  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  2.0
2  4.32454  1.77600  0.04454  0.00000  NaN
3  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  2.00000  NaN
```

---

Explanation:

First, stack to remove NaNs

```
df.stack()

0  0     5.29559
   2     2.38176
   4     0.51521
   6     0.04454
   7     0.00000
1  0     0.00000
   5     0.00000
   8     0.00000
   11    0.00000
   12    2.00000
2  0     4.32454
   2     1.77600
   4     0.04454
   6     0.00000
3  0     0.00000
   5     0.00000
   8     0.00000
   11    2.00000 
dtype: float64
```

You'll notice the inner level of the index isn't monotonically increasing. let's fix that with groupby.apply

```
_.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True))

0  0    5.29559
   1    2.38176
   2    0.51521
   3    0.04454
   4    0.00000
1  0    0.00000
   1    0.00000
   2    0.00000
   3    0.00000
   4    2.00000
2  0    4.32454
   1    1.77600
   2    0.04454
   3    0.00000
3  0    0.00000
   1    0.00000
   2    0.00000
   3    2.00000
dtype: float64
```

now we unstack

```
_.unstack()

         0        1        2        3    4
0  5.29559  2.38176  0.51521  0.04454  0.0
1  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  2.0
2  4.32454  1.77600  0.04454  0.00000  NaN
3  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  2.00000  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom function to remove null values from each row:

```
>>> df.agg(lambda x: pd.Series([v for v in x if pd.notna(v)]), axis=1)

         0        1        2        3    4
0  5.29559  2.38176  0.51521  0.04454  0.0
1  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  2.0
2  4.32454  1.77600  0.04454  0.00000  NaN
3  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  2.00000  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(your_table)
df = df.dropna(axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 5), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])
```